# Implode ids within a while loop and add commas between

Tags: php, loops, implode

I'm trying to display some sub-content so I need to get the child id's of their parent.

This is how I wanted to do it:

```
$ids        = "SELECT * FROM `web_categories` WHERE parent_id = 14 AND published = 1";
$idscon     = $conn->query($ids);
while ($ids = $idscon->fetch_array()){
    $idss .= $ids['id'];
}

$project1       = "SELECT * FROM `web_content` WHERE catid in ('$idss') AND state = 1";
$projectcon1    = $conn->query($project1);
$projectcr1     = array();
while ($projectcr1[] = $projectcon1->fetch_array());
```

I tried imploding `$idss` like this:

```
$implode = implode(',', $idss);
```

But this gives me `Invalid arguments passed`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `$idss .= $ids['id'];` to `$idss[] = $ids['id'];` and instead of `implode()` use the `join()`.

Comment: i hope now u have three solutions now, try it and share your feedback.

Comment: Thanks, the first comment worked, i'll accept your answer @FrayneKonok

Comment: @devpro, We both did the same solution, But as i did it first so i deserve this... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing wrong in the **first while loop.**

Here it is, *`$idss .= $ids['id'];`*, You are doing wrong this. You are storing value in a variable as string, but when you try to implode this... It throws an error!!! Cause `implode()` use to make array into string. So follow the below steps.

Change `$idss .= $ids['id'];` to `$idss[] = $ids['id'];` and instead of `implode()` use the `join()`.

Create an array names `$idss`, and push or insert the ids into that array. Then implode/join that IDs.

```
$idss = array();
while ($ids = $idscon->fetch_array()){
    $idss[] = $ids['id'];
}
$implode = implode(',', $idss);
```

Now you can use this `$implode` variable in the next query.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to store all IDs in an array, something like `$yourIDs[] = $ids['id'];` inside your first while loop.

With `$idss .= $ids['id'];` you can't use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) because result of this action should be something like "1234" without any single comma.

*You just need to use like that:*

```
<?php
$yourIDs = array();
while ($ids = $idscon->fetch_array()){
    $yourIDs[] = $ids['id']; // this will save all IDs into $yourIDs array.
}
$idss = implode(',',$yourIDs); // result of this should be 1,2,3,4 etc.
?>
```

Comment: In my case, I had $yourIDs = ''; instead of $yourIDs = array();. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you could most likely do that in one query

```
SELECT * FROM `web_content` WHERE `catid` in (
    SELECT `id` FROM `web_categories` WHERE `parent_id` = 14 AND `published` = 1
) AND `state` = 1
```

The original code was, in effect, doing exactly this but in two stages - sub-queries can be slow sometimes but it does depend on the size of the db and the number of expected results. It is true that joins can be and generally are more efficient than dependant subqueries so perhaps that is another option to explore. As mysql executes the query plan from the outside to the inside rather than the intuitive inside to outside subqueries can cause the server to crawl - it really depends on the complexity of the subquery and the amount of data that has to be processed.

Comment: @RamRaider, Do you think the sub query like this can perform well, I think it will take much time, please Explain this.

Comment: Nice solution, frayne answered a bit earlier, but this is cleaner

Comment: @twan, You can also use this, but the explanation is important. I think **RamRaider** will add the explanation.